# Circular motion at a fixed angle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, centripetal-force, angular-velocity

An equal amount of white solution of AgCl was taken in 3 test tubes. One test tube was centrifuged at a 0-degree angle, one at a 180-degree angle, and the other at a 45-degree angle. Will the result be the same or different in each case? What is the cause of the result?